# TypeScript: Is it possible to implement abstract class property by property inherited from type specified in abstract one?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

The abstract class `ParentClass` in the code below need to work with abstract property `significantEntity` (which is the instance on the class, inherited from  abstract `SignificantEntityParent`). Off course, below code is invalid, because `significantEntity` implementations has different type than `SignificantEntityParent`.

```js
abstract class SignificantEntityParent {}
class SignificantEntity1 extends SignificantEntityParent {}
class SignificantEntity2 extends SignificantEntityParent {}

abstract class ParentClass {

  protected abstract significantEntity: SignificantEntityParent;

  public testMethod(): void {
    console.log(this.significantEntity);
  }
}

class TestClass1 extends ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // invalid!
    this.significantEntity = new SignificantEntity1();
  }
}

class TestClass2 extends ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // invalid!
    this.significantEntity = new SignificantEntity2();
  }
}
```

I tried walk-around with abstract generic method `getSignificantEntity<SignificantEntity extends SignificantEntityParent>(): SignificantEntity`.

```
abstract class ParentClassA {

  protected abstract getSignificantEntity<SignificantEntity extends SignificantEntityParent>(): SignificantEntity;

  public logSignificantEntity(): void {
    console.log(this.getSignificantEntity());
  }
}

class TestClassA1 extends ParentClassA {

  private significantEntity: SignificantEntity1;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.significantEntity = new SignificantEntity1();
  }

  protected getSignificantEntity(): SignificantEntity1 {
     return this.significantEntity;
  }
}

class TestClassA2 extends ParentClassA {

  private significantEntity: SignificantEntity2;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.significantEntity = new SignificantEntity2();
  }

  protected getSignificantEntity(): SignificantEntity2 {
    return this.significantEntity;
  }
}
```

I get a lot of errors:

- TS2416: Property 'getSignificantEntity' in type 'TestClassA' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ParentClassA'.
- Type '() => SignifcantEntity1' is not assignable to type 'SignificantEntity extends SignificantEntityParent>() => SignificantEntity'.
- Type 'SignificantEntity1' is not assignable to type 'Significant entity'.

I can not understand what TypeScript trying to tell me. Is there valid approach to work with `significantEntity` inside abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be clearly documented, but the abstract properties and methods of [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes) have to be *declared* in concrete subclasses; they can't just be *used*.  That means you can fix your first example by adding concrete property declarations:

```
class TestClass1 extends ParentClass {
    significantEntity: SignificantEntity1; // declaration   
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.significantEntity = new SignificantEntity1();
    }
}

class TestClass2 extends ParentClass {
    significantEntity: SignificantEntity2; // declaration
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.significantEntity = new SignificantEntity2();
    }
}
```

Of course, if all you're doing in the constructor is initializing a property, you can drop the constructor and use an explicit [property initializer](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html#property-initializer), which serves as both declaration and initialization:

```
class TestClass1 extends ParentClass {
    significantEntity = new SignificantEntity1();
}

class TestClass2 extends ParentClass {
    significantEntity= new SignificantEntity2();
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!